# List Item as Variable Assignment

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

So lets say my list is

```
Colors=["red", "blue", "green", "purple"]
```

Then, I want to assign red to `[1,2,3,4]`.
For example: `red=[1,2,3,4]`

How do you take an item in a list and assign something to it?

Clarification: without just changing the Colors list and by creating a whole new variable red.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using a `dict`:

```
>>> myobj = {}
>>> for i in ["red", "blue", "green", "purple"]:
...    myobj[i] = []
...
>>> myobj['red'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> myobj['red']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> myobj.keys()
['blue', 'purple', 'green', 'red']
```

As shown above, you can use `dict.keys()` to get the **keys** (colors, in this example) of the dictionary.

Comment: Just to add a little, you could also access the colors by looking at `myobj.keys()`.